# common navigation drawer on different activities

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I have built an application with an navigation drawer activity in it but now I want it to be present on my other activities as well. I don't want to handle events again and again in different classes.

Also I got suggestions like making one base class and extend that but as I cannot extend more than one class.

Also I also want to use fragments so that I did not have to write the same code again and again
My `activity_main.xml` is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`nav_header.xml` is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/bcet_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@string/college_name"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/college_name_full" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.bcetapp.bcetbeta;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        Intent intent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_student_list) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_staff_list) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_action_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact_us) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    /****************************************************************************************USER DEFINED FUNCTIONS******************************************************************/
    public void viewMyProfile(View view){
        /*intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);*/
    }

}
```

`activity_main_drawer.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_student_list"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_group"
            android:title="Students" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_staff_list"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_glasses"
            android:title=" College Staff" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_help"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
            android:title="help" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Settings" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="More">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:title="About us"
                android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_info"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_action_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
                android:title="Share App" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_contact_us"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="contact us" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not as easy. There are 2 tech-ticks to achieve it. One is to create use fragment second one is to add the whole code in all activities.

To achieve your result in above case, Add the fragment in your activity and replace/add activities as your required

Answer (score 0):

> Also i got suggestions like making one base class and extend that but as I cannot extend more than one class.

True, but the thing about class extension is that you can create a base class that extends AppCompatActivity, and then make your activities extend that base class:

```
public class BaseClass extends AppCompatActivity...
public class MainActivity extends BaseClass...
```

This will implicitly cause your MainActivity to extend AppCompatActivity.